# Joining models in cake php

Tags: cakephp, join

I have this NPO table which has one template. A template in turn has a theme. I want to retrieve which theme was selected by `Npo`.

I have following relation setup:

> NPO - template on npo.id = template.npoid Template - theme on theme.id
>   = template.template_theme_id

And I am using:

```
$this->Npo->bindmodel(array(
  'hasOne' => array(
    'NpoTemplate' => array(
      'className' => 'NpoTemplate'
    )
  )
), false);

$this->NpoTemplate->bindmodel(array(
  'hasOne' => array(
    'TemplateTheme' => array(
      'className' => 'TemplateTheme',
      'fields' => 'TemplateTheme.html'
    )
  )
), false);

$arrUserSite = $this->Npo->find('first', array(
  'conditions'=> array(
    'Npo.address' => $user
  )
));
```

But it does not fetch anything from TemplateTheme. Instead it writes a seperate query for this table and does not consider it in the join.

I have set `recursive` level to `3`

Please help. I don't really understand how the cake association works.

Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Comment: `belogsTo`: Did you mean... `belongsTo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up your relationships in a single **bindModel()** call.

```
$this->Npo->bindmodel(array(
  'hasOne' => array(
    'NpoTemplate' => array(
      'foreignKey' => false,
      'conditions' => array(
        'Npo.id = NpoTemplate.npoid'
      )
    ),
    'TemplateTheme' => array(
      'foreignKey' => false,
      'conditions' => array(
        'NpoTemplate.template_theme_id = TemplateTheme.id'
      )
    )
  )
));


$arrUserSite = $this->Npo->find('first', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'Npo.address' => $user 
  )
));
```

You'll probably need to tweak the bindModel setup because I'm not 100% sure of your database structure. Good luck.